# Declined flags: What am I not understanding about how the site should work?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer, specific-answer

Recently, a couple of my flags on answers have been declined. The first time I figured, "OK, let it go. Mods make mistakes, too."

The second time in such a short interval, I have to wonder if I've misunderstood something? I don't want a ban...

First time I marked the following as VLQ. The flag was declined, but the Answer then deleted by others from review - they obviously agreed with me. This should have been a comment, at best. (The question was not clear and contained too little information. The OP finally ended up posting the work-around that solved it for them.)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53789344/3077495

The second time: I marked as NAA. This should have been a comment on another answer, at best. It does not answer the question; it says the Answer only worked for them when they did something a bit different.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54012032/3077495

Comment: I can't see that deleted answer, but VLQ flags are not for posts that "should be comments", but for gibberish posts.

Comment: The second one, I tend to agree with you. Kinda sad that you flagged and not voted, though. If you vote on these posts, you can let regular users to act on them without having to involve moderators.

Comment: The answer you reference wasn't deleted by review, it was [just deleted by three others](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53789344/timeline).

Comment: That first one is indeed  not VLQ, as @yivi predicted, so using a VLQ flag is wrong. Despite it being more a comment then answer, it is an attempt at answering and as such flags should not be used. Use down votes instead. Second one is borderline NAA, you would have needed some luck and reviewers that are on top of the queue to prevent a mod would handle it, who probably err on the side of cautious. Also down votes help here, maybe a tactical comment that explains to reviewers why they have to judge that answer.

Comment: If you think that an answer is not a good answer then  *downvote it*, don't flag it.  Also just because you think *an answer to the question* isn't a very good answer doesn't mean it should be a comment.  Comments aren't for "bad answers", comments are for clarifications of the posts that they're commenting on; neither of these *answers* were doing that.  They were answering the question.

Comment: @Makoto Hm? Two of the three delete-voters did so from review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21694957 So it is arguably more correct to say it was deleted from review than not.

Comment: What you don't understand is simply that flagging has been slowly neutered over the years so that the only ones worth casting are custom moderator flags. You can raise the other ones, but it's not worth your time to go back and see what happened to them.

Comment: I've never actually seen a case where VLQ could technically be used, per the guidance. Every post can technically be edited to salvage it.

Comment: @TheWanderer There is plenty of gibberish and nonsense posted, as well as true non-answers. Just visit the late answers queue, or the New Answers to Old Questions 10k tools page and you're bound to see a few. That you don't see them does not mean the problems that those flags are meant to address do not exist, if anything it means that those flags are effective at dealing with those problems. The problems that are commonly lamented as not being solvable using the flagging systems are not solvable as such because it should be left to the community to solve those problems, not moderators.

Comment: The first answer is one I refer to as saying "water is wet".  Stating the obvious without any real help. It is an answer, but I'd have no problem deleting it. The second one is an answer, but needs more explanation. They're those line ball types of posts, that can be argued either way. These line ball posts are a real pain. I'm not sure they really bring any value to the site.

Comment: @YvetteColomb The second one is IMO a reply/comment to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42607866/3077495 in the same discussion (an edit removed that information, making the answer even less comprehendable). The person is saying they could only get that approach to work when they changed how something is used. That's why I flagged it as NAA, because in my book it's a comment on that answer...

Comment: @yivi " Kinda sad that you flagged and not voted, though. If you vote on these posts, you can let regular users to act on them without having to involve moderators." 1) How will regular users act on something like this if I simply DV? 2) Doesn't flagging put these in the NAA / LQ queues? If such things are there *then* regular users "can act on them"? Otherwise, as far as I can tell, these things are going to go under the radar? I across #2 in the "First Answers" queue.

Comment: Downvoted posts can be voted to be deleted by users with the appropriate privileges.

Comment: @yivi Ah, I didn't realize that. Do they appear in some kind of queue? Because mostly I work in very low-traffic tags (Office-related) with few users that have a lot of rep. It's even a problem getting questions put on hold...

Comment: @CindyMeister  I didn't see the original edit. It's definitely naa. It's possible the mod who declined your flag didn't see the original edit

Comment: @YvetteColomb The edit occurred after I posted here (meta effect)...

Comment: @CindyMeister ah ok. I'm not sure why it was declined.

Comment: @YvetteColomb The post is *providing a solution to the problem*.  That's not "Not an Answer".  Saying that another answer doesn't work in addition to stating what *does* work doesn't make a post not an answer.  There's nothing you can *add* to a post that *makes* it not an answer when it was before.  That's why the original flag was declined, and why your deletion is entirely unwarranted.

Comment: @CindyMeister Intentionally making a post worse just to try to get it deleted is a *terrible* thing to do.  Why in the world would you do that?

Comment: @Servy I didn't do anything to the post except rollback an edit that made the post unclear -  put it back to its original wording. The reference to the other answer on which it was based was removed. Without that, that post makes no sense.

Comment: @CindyMeister What about the edit made the post unclear.  The edit removed information not relevant to the answer to the question.  What was unclear about it?  Why does the answer need to say that another answer doesn't work to make sense?  it just needs to state what *does* work.

Comment: @Servy The edit removed the referral one of the other Answers, there being more than one. IMO it only makes any sense by knowing which answer is being referred to as this is additional information *only* for that answer (a `--` in the "the @listfile mode."). And for a code segment near the *end* of that answer, meaning it won't be obvious at a glance. I have no trouble with removing excess text, but for me the reference `MC ND's solution` is a key part.

Comment: @CindyMeister It removed the statement that another answer is wrong.  It kept the part stating what the solution to the problem is.  That's the part that's *actually the answer*.  It doesn't need to state that another answer is wrong to do that.

Comment: @Servy In it's current form it reads like a question.

Comment: @YvetteColomb What's the question?  It states what they did to solve the problem.  That's an answer, not a question.